# Cakebake something like in Symfony2

Tags: cakephp, symfony, cakephp-2.0

I really like cakebake functionality in cakephp. now i want to use Symfony2..

Is there is any such functionality in Symfony2 .

Please let me know

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any interactive tool like bake, but symfony2 has a console functionality as well to create bundle, controllers and crud app instantly.

check out this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

or

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html